# Changing colors of bars on the plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(trt=c("TAVERN","Long Term Care","Grocery Store","Restaurant"),
                 outcome=c("a","b","c","d"))

ggplot(df,aes(trt, outcome)) + 
  geom_col() +
  geom_point(colour = 'red') +
  ggtitle("Failing rate in different facility types") + 
  labs(x="Facility type",y="Failing rate") + 
  theme(panel.background = element_blank()) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("purple","green", "red", "orange"))
```

I tried to change the color in the ggplot manually.

[image]

But I fail to do so. Really confused about that.

**Question.** How to set up the parameters of `ggplot()` function in order 
to change the bars' colors?

Comment: Do you want to change the color of the bars or the dots? If you want to change the bars you need `scale_fill_manual()`

Comment: You haven't told ggplot what to give colors to or where they should come from. Some variable will need to be assigned to color inside an `aes` call. Also,keep in mind that bars have a fill, so your color scale wouldn't affect the fill of the bars

Comment: Try `geom_col(aes(fill = trt)) +` then `scale_fill_manual`, like @Mako212 said.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to change the colors of the bars. Then, you need to specify the `fill` option of the `geom_col`.

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(trt=c("TAVERN","Long Term Care","Grocery Store","Restaurant"),
                 outcome=c("a","b","c","d"))
ggplot(df,aes(trt, outcome)) + 
  geom_col(fill=c("purple","green", "red", "orange")) + 
  geom_point(colour = 'red') + 
  ggtitle("Failing rate in different facility types") +
  labs(x="Facility type", y="Failing rate") +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank())
```

Alternatively, you can set the `fill` aesthetics.  Note that `fill` is for the interior.  `colour` is for the boundary.

```
ggplot(df,aes(trt, outcome, fill=trt)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_point(colour = 'red') + 
  ggtitle("Failing rate in different facility types") +
  labs(x="Facility type", y="Failing rate") +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank()) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("purple","green", "red", "orange"))
```